# Are variable type annotations useful everywhere?

Tags: python, annotations, python-typing

For example:

```py
def some_func(num: int) -> str:
    var1: str = other_func(num)
    var2: str = 'hi'
    return var2 + var1
```

Is it OK to do annotations for inside variables (`var1`, `var2`) or are they redundant? Are there any conventions, or standards for such situations?

Comment: Voted to close as opinion-based, but these do seem redundant (especially if `other_func`'s return type is correctly annotated)

Comment: I don't agree this is opinion-based. If all functions, classes and constants are typed, then annotations within functions are redundant from a type-checking perspective, and serve only to improve readability (which is up to the developer to decide). That is, it's not opinion that they are redundant given typed functions etc.

Comment: moreover, if say `other_func` here is _not_ typed, then `str` is not redundant in `var1: str`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, type annotations may usefully be added to local variables.
As an independent item, some annotations are redundant,
and that doesn't necessarily prevent them from being useful.

Had you coded `var2 = 'hi'`, then `var2` would still have `str` type.
Your (redundant) annotation isn't telling the machine anything new,
and here it isn't being helpful to humans since the intent is simple and clear.
However, coding `var3: Foo = complex_function()` might be in the same
situation yet very helpful to humans who seldom call that function
and who have forgotten it always returns a Foo.
And of course if that complex function is implemented in C and lacks stubs,
then automated inference can't do better than a vacuous `Any` type.

If a conditional farther down will sometimes assign `None`,
then you might code e.g.
`var4: str | None = 'hi'`.

---

Often we write code like `var5: dict[str, int] = {}`
since both `mypy` and humans need to know details of the mapping,
and an empty `dict` does not express those details.

---

When in doubt you can ask `mypy` to
[reveal_type](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#reveal-type).
Or use a
[beartype](https://pypi.org/project/beartype)
decorator to request runtime checking -- if
your code strays outside the declared types
it will raise a fatal diagnostic.

Explicit types reveal Author's Intent,
and can help prevent a maintenance engineer
from accidentally introducing a bug,
e.g. turning some mandatory type into an `Optional` type
by initializing it to `None`.
In a [@jit](https://pypi.org/project/numba)-decorated
method that can mean the difference between
compiling to an efficient C `int` versus
having to do lots of expensive runtime type verification.

Answer (score 1):

Local variable annotations are usually unnecessary since:

- Function return types are often already provided/inferable. (e.g., `other_func` may have already been typed `int -> str`.)
- [Opinion]: Adding an annotation to the function is simpler than variable annotations.

  Compare:

  ```
  def ordinal(x):
      special = {1: "st", 2: "nd", 3: "rd"}
      return special.get(x, "th")

  first: str = ordinal(1)
  second: str = ordinal(2)
  third: str = ordinal(3)
  fourth: str = ordinal(4)
  fifth: str = ordinal(5)
  ```

  versus just doing it once in the signature:

  ```
  def ordinal(x: int) -> str:
      special = {1: "st", 2: "nd", 3: "rd"}
      return special.get(x, "th")

  first = ordinal(1)
  second = ordinal(2)
  third = ordinal(3)
  fourth = ordinal(4)
  fifth = ordinal(5)
  ```

  Note: some tools can already infer the return type is `str`, but it's still better to annotate explicitly so that the tools can function fast.
- [Opinion]: Local variables are many, and yet scope-limited (short-lived). Adding annotations increases verbosity. Thus, it's usually not worth the tradeoff.

Type inference implies that static analysis tools can already detect what the types are, and editors can already display them via "inlay hints".